# how to add scala-test support to intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

How do I install scala-test with intellij.  The video on the intellij website shows them adding a library dependency with scala-test showing up on the list.  I don't have that however as I'll need to install scala-test somehow first.  The quickstart on  the scala website just seems to have a link to a jar file.  Do I configure the IDE in some way to point to that jar file as a global library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need for a global library. Intellij IDEA supports adding libraries to your project directly from Maven. Here's how:

1. Go to File -> Project Structure
2. Select the Dependencies tab
3. Click the + sign at the bottom to create a new library
4. Choose "New Library" and seleect "From Maven" to add a new library from the public Maven repository

This brings up a search dialog which you can use to find the Maven dependency you want. Try searching for "org.scalatest:scalatest" to get the list of scalatest libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. However, could not download successfully from "org.scalatest:scalatest". Used "org.scala-tools.testing:scalatest" which worked.

Comment: As of now, using "org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11" gets you access to the latest version (3.0.1). I derived this from the groupId and artifactId in the Maven install instructions at http://www.scalatest.org/install.

Answer (score 5):

To install the latest version of **[ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/)** and its dependencies in **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2**, you need:

1. Visit http://www.scalatest.org/install (section `To include ScalaTest 3.0.1 in your Maven project`) to fetch a list of reqiered libraries full names with the following structure `{groupId}:{artifactId}:{version}`, e.g.

   - `org.scalactic:scalactic_2.11:3.0.1`
   - `org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.0.1`

     > Make sure that libraries names contain a Scala version you use in you project, i.e. above libraries are compatible with Scala 2.11 and [not working with the new 2.12 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-refarrayops).
2. Go to `File` ⇒ `Project Structure...` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Windows):
   [image: Main menu]
3. Go to `Project Settings | Modules` section and click on `Dependencies` tab. Then click `+` ⇒ `2 Library...` ⇒ `From Maven...`:
   [image: Project Structure dialog]
4. Type in the full library name to install, then click `Search` button (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), select the library you need and click `OK`:
   [image: Download dialog]
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until all dependencies are installed.