# Using Scala 2.12 with Spark 2.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, abi, binary-compatibility

At the Spark 2.1 [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) it's mentioned that

> Spark runs on Java 7+, Python 2.6+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.1.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).

at the Scala 2.12 [release news](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0) it's also mentioned that:

> Although Scala 2.11 and 2.12 are mostly source compatible to facilitate cross-building, they are not binary compatible. This allows us to keep improving the Scala compiler and standard library.

But when I build an uber jar (using Scala 2.12) and run it on Spark 2.1. every thing work just fine.

and I know its not any official source but at the [47 degree blog](https://www.47deg.com/blog/apache-spark-two-point-zero/) they mentioned that Spark 2.1 does support Scala 2.12.

How can one explain those (conflicts?) pieces of information ?

Comment: There is a formal difference i.e. *"we support that version, we have tested it, and if you have issues then it's a bug on our side"* vs. *"do it your way, experiment if you wish, but if you have issues then don't come back whining"*.

Comment: yea but how can it work if scala 2.11 is not binary compatible with 2.12?

Comment: Not compatible means that there is at least 1 issue. Could be OK for 99.99% of the API calls. How much did you test with your custom Uber-JAR? Maybe 15%?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 38):

Spark **does not** support Scala 2.12. You can follow [SPARK-14220](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14220) (*Build and test Spark against Scala 2.12*) to get up to date status.

**update**:
[Spark 2.4 added](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-0.html) an experimental Scala 2.12 support.

Comment: could have been added as comment

Comment: Spark 2.4 now supports Scala 2.12 as an experimentally.

Comment: 2.12 support is no longer experimental - it's now GA - see Spark [2.4.1 release notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-1.html).

Comment: `Scala 2.12` may be supported, but as of `Spark 2.4.x` the [pre-built binaries](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) are compiled with `Scala 2.11` (except version `2.4.2`).

Answer (score 4):

Scala 2.12 is officially supported (and required) as of Spark 3.  Summary:

- Spark 2.0 - 2.3: Required Scala 2.11
- Spark 2.4: Supported Scala 2.11 and Scala 2.12, but not really cause almost all runtimes only supported Scala 2.11.
- Spark 3: Only Scala 2.12 is supported

Using a Spark runtime that's compiled with one Scala version and a JAR file that's compiled with another Scala version is dangerous and causes strange bugs.  For example, as noted [here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/upgrate-to-spark-3-scala-2-12/), using a Scala 2.11 compiled JAR on a Spark 3 cluster will cause this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps`.

Look [at all the poor Spark users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-refarrayops) running into this very error.

Make sure to look into Scala cross compilation and understand the `%%` operator in SBT to limit your suffering.  Maintaining Scala projects is hard and minimizing your dependencies is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer, I believe it is a typo https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html has no mention of scala 2.12.

Also, if we look at timings Scala 2.12 was not released untill November 2016 and Spark 2.0.0 was released on July 2016.

References:
https://spark.apache.org/news/index.html

www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/