# SBT dependency Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

This is an *SBT* build file which I have written

```
name := "HelloSpark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1"
```

when I run `sbt package` I get error message

> [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.1.1: not found
>
> [error] Total time: 2 s, completed Oct 29, 2017 1:01:13 AM

Comment: In general, you can't use one version of the _Scala_ compiler with a library built with a different version. Here you are specifying a _Scala_ 2.12 compiler with a library built for _Scala_ 2.11. That's not going to work. To ensure libraries match the compiler, you can skip the version suffix if you use the`%%` operator between the organization and artifact name. That is, use a dependency of `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"` instead of `"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1"`.  _Spark_ doesn't currently support 2.12, so set `scalaVersion := "2.11.11"`.

Comment: Are you using a corporate network? Are you perhaps behind a proxy? Can you show the entire log from `sbt package`? (edit your question and paste the output). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use Scala 2.11

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"
```

[using scala 2.12 with spark 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887359/using-scala-2-12-with-spark-2-1)

> Spark does not support Scala 2.12

Just in case, you can find binaries for `spark-core` here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11

Comment: HI Dmytro, Thanks for ypur suggestion. It makes sense now. However I have scala 2.12 installed in my system. and changing the scala version is throwing another error. --- at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.11: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.11: not found
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Oct 29, 2017 3:56:44 AM
.  -- Could you please suggest any workaround

Comment: @devD What is your version of sbt?

Comment: My version of sbt is 0.13.16

Comment: @devD It doesn't matter what version of _Scala_ is installed on your system, as _sbt_ will use the version specified by `scalaVersion`. It looks to me like you have a network problem. Do you access the Internet through a proxy?