# How to fix missing parameter type for foreach() in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, intellij-idea

Below is my scala 11.12 code

```
val res= Config().getConfig(source_fields.toLowerCase).entrySet()
    println("Entry set is:"+ res.toString)
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("^[$].*$")
    println("Regex pattern is: "+pattern)
    var query=""
    res.forEach(elem => {
      val matcher = pattern.matcher(elem.getValue.render().replace("\"", ""))
      query += "," + (if (matcher.matches()) "'" + matcher.group().replace("$", "") + "'" + " as " + elem.getKey.replace("\"", "`")
      else elem.getValue.render().replace("\"", "") + " as " + elem.getKey.replace("\"", "`")
        )
    }
    )
```

[image: screen shot]

This builds successfully if I add sdk-2.12. But my cluster is setup with scala 2.11 and it fails there with error - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-refarrayops)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this just by using res.asScala.foreach

Answer (score 1):

This kind of Exception points to a mismatch of scala versions, either you mix scala versions of dependencies, or your scala version between compilation and runtime environment differ.

So if you build your program with scala 2.12 and try to run it using scala 2.11 you will likely get this exception

Comment: If I change my sdk to 2.11, It throws an error for line 'res.forEach(elem => {' saying "Missing parameter type" and fails to compile. If i change it back to 2.12 , it builds successfully and then fails at println(df.collect()) with error - [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row;@3b6fa89a. 
This code was working fine few weeks ago but failing now