# Kafka start error on MAC .. something related to java and scala ... NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, nosuchmethoderror

i have downloaded kafka from here https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/3.4.0/kafka_2.13-3.4.0.tgz

Zookeeper starts with the command

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

but when i ran this command

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

i got this

```
[2023-03-12 14:25:29,772] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:43) ~[kafka_2.13-3.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:92) [kafka_2.13-3.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [kafka_2.13-3.4.0.jar:?]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Option.orNull(Lscala/$less$colon$less;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at kafka.utils.Exit$.exit(Exit.scala:28)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:128)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

I tried to check if it has scala lib in libs and orNull method exists in in that scala version

Comment: Look's strange. Out of curiosity, have you tried to download another version on the official website?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328948/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-refarrayops https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: Please show `java.class.path`. There should be line `INFO Server environment:java.class.path=...` in the output of `zookeeper-server-start.sh`  and `INFO Client environment:java.class.path=...` in the output of `kafka-server-start.sh`. It's better to show the whole output of the both commands. Maybe something confuses scala 2.13 and 2.12.

Comment: The signature of `refArrayOps` is different in 2.12 `def refArrayOps(scala.Array[scala.Any]): scala.Array[scala.Any]` (scalap) `public <T> T[] refArrayOps(T[])` (javap) [api](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.17/scala/Predef$.html#refArrayOps[T%3C:AnyRef](xs:Array[T]):scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.ofRef[T]) and 2.13 `def refArrayOps(scala.Array[scala.Any]): scala.Any` (scalap) `public <T> T[] refArrayOps(T[])` (javap) [api](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/Predef$.html#refArrayOps[T%3C:AnyRef](xs:Array[T]):scala.collection.ArrayOps[T])

Comment: If you've installed Scala separately, your kafka version needs to match. Looks like you still have Scala 2.12 on your system

Comment: @OneCricketeer Well, I have Scala 2.12 installed in my system (Ubuntu) but `zookeeper-server-start.sh` and `kafka-server-start.sh` from `kafka_2.13-3.4.0` run. Doesn't Kafka use `scala-library` from `kafka_2.13-3.4.0/libs` and not installed in the system? At least at the site it's [written](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) that Java 8+ should be installed, not Scala. But maybe this can be different at MacOS.

Comment: @Dmytro Zookeeper doesn't use Scala. Kafka still relies on OS PATH variables, of which scala binaries would conflict with JVM classpath. Yes, Java needs installed, but Kafka is compiled with Scala bytecode, which is version specific... In other words, if Scala is not installed on the system, Kafka works fine because it'll only use its local libraries

Comment: @OneCricketeer Well, maybe I misunderstand but you said that if Scala is installed then Kafka version needs to match. I'm telling you that at my system Scala 2.12 is installed and `kafka_2.13-3.4.0` doesn't match but runs (because uses Kafka local Scala library and not the one that is installed). In my output of `kafka-server-start.sh`, `java.class.path` has `libs/scala-library-2.13.10.jar` and not Scala 2.12 from my system `$PATH`. But maybe something is different in OP's setting.

Comment: @Gireeshd Glad you figured it out, but Kafka doesn't need Python, so it's not clear why you saw that in any logs

Comment: I apologize for the confusion earlier. Regarding the issue with the conflicting class in Hive and Kafka, I have commented out the line that sets the CLASSPATH environment variable to include hive libraries . This was necessary to resolve the conflict and avoid issues. By doing this, the class that exists in both libraries will only be loaded from one location, preventing conflicts... sorry for pasting  clion cmake build log earlier..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops