# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor: method <init>()V not found while running Play App with SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, nosuchmethoderror, snakeyaml

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor: method ()V not
> found
> at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.(DeserializationUtils.java:397)
> at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.readYamlTree(DeserializationUtils.java:209)
> at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.deserializeIntoTree(DeserializationUtils.java:145)
> at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readContents(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:168)
> at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:97)
> at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
> at com.atlassian.oai.validator.util.OpenApiLoader.readSwaggerParserResult(OpenApiLoader.java:79)
> at com.atlassian.oai.validator.util.OpenApiLoader.loadApi(OpenApiLoader.java:48)
> at com.atlassian.oai.validator.OpenApiInteractionValidator$Builder.build(OpenApiInteractionValidator.java:643)

This is coming after updating the version of snakeyaml from 1.3 to 2.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75880410/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-hadoop-hive-common-fileutils-mkdir-while https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: Please provide reproduction: build files (`build.sbt`, `pom.xml` etc.), what code causes the error. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is snakeyaml 1.3? Mvnrepository knows 1.4-1.33, 2.0 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml Did you mean snakeyaml 1.33 (1.3x)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, snakeyaml 2.0 doesn't have empty-arg constructor for the class `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor`.

In snakeyaml 1.33 such constructor existed but was deprecated.

In snakeyaml 2.0 try to replace

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.{LoaderOptions, Yaml}
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor

val safeConstructor = new SafeConstructor
val yaml = new Yaml(safeConstructor)
```

with

```
val loaderOptions = new LoaderOptions
// loaderOptions.setCodePointLimit(...)
// ...
val safeConstructor = new SafeConstructor(loaderOptions)
val yaml = new Yaml(safeConstructor)
```

https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-loading-yaml

https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/master/src/test/java/examples/SafeConstructorExampleTest.java

Answer (score 0):

For me it was "uap-java" lib that didn't support "snakeyaml 2.0". Upgrading to latest version (from 1.5.2 to 1.5.4 so far) solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

snake yaml 2.x, the default constructor is not supported.

To read yaml file for kubernetes definition,
you can use jackson library ObjectMapper class

you can find the code, through the link below.

[io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Serialization.unmarshal](https://angelinurs.github.io/example/issue/kubernetes/fabric8/snakeyaml/kubectl/java/2023-12-12-issue-fabric8-snakeyaml/)