# Gradle built of Micronaut-based app breaks with NoSuchMethodError from 3rd-party snakeyaml lib, caused by incompat. with OpenAPI Generator plugin

Tags: gradle, openapi-generator, micronaut-openapi

since last week (first occurence on 9th of May 2023) our Gradle build of a Micronaut-based application fails with

```
[...]

> Task :openApiGenerate FAILED
Error snake-parsing yaml content
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor: method 'void <init>()' not found
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.DeserializationUtils$CustomSnakeYamlConstructor.<init>(DeserializationUtils.java:393)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.readYamlTree(DeserializationUtils.java:207)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.DeserializationUtils.deserializeIntoTree(DeserializationUtils.java:143)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readContents(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:165)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:94)
        at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
        at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toContext(CodegenConfigurator.java:589)
        at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:647)
        at org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask.doWork(GenerateTask.kt:825)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java
        [...]
```

This project makes use of--among other things--

- [Gradle's OpenAPI Generator plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.openapi.generator),
- Micronaut `3.9.1`

After investigating some possible root causes, to me it seems to be caused by an incompatible change with 3rd-party lib `snakeyaml` between its version `1.33` to `2.0`, and "cross-usage" of this lib:

### Micronaut `3.9.1`

makes use of snakeyaml version `2.0`, declared in his [BOM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/micronaut/micronaut-bom/3.9.1/micronaut-bom-3.9.1.pom):

```
$ ./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency org.yaml:snakeyaml
[...]

> Task :dependencyInsight
org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0 (by constraint)
  Variant compile:
    | Attribute Name                     | Provided | Requested         |
    |------------------------------------|----------|-------------------|
    | org.gradle.status                  | release  |                   |
    | org.gradle.category                | library  | library           |
    | org.gradle.libraryelements         | jar      | classes+resources |
    | org.gradle.usage                   | java-api | java-api          |
    | org.gradle.dependency.bundling     |          | external          |
    | org.gradle.jvm.environment         |          | standard-jvm      |
    | org.gradle.jvm.version             |          | 17                |
    | org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type |          | jvm               |

org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0
+--- io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:3.9.1
|    \--- compileClasspath
[...]
```

** Confirmed by explicitly querying BOM's dependency:

```
$ curl --silent https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/micronaut/micronaut-bom/3.9.1/micronaut-bom-3.9.1.pom | grep snakeyaml
 <snakeyaml.version>2.0</snakeyaml.version>
     <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
     <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>
```

### Current version `6.6.0` of Gradle's OpenAPI plugin

makes use of snakeyaml version `1.33`; found this by launching Gradle built with `--scan` option, showing here excerpt of tab "Build (!!!) dependencies":

```
build.gradle
  com.google.cloud.tools.jib:com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.plugin:3.+ => 3.3.2
  com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties.gradle.plugin:2.+ => 2.4.1
  io.micronaut.application:io.micronaut.application.gradle.plugin:3.+ => 3.7.9
  org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.8.21
  org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt.gradle.plugin:1.8.21
  org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen:org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen.gradle.plugin:1.8.21
  org.openapi.generator:org.openapi.generator.gradle.plugin:6.+ => 6.6.0
    org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:6.6.0
      org.openapitools:openapi-generator:6.6.0
        com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.0 => 2.15.0
        com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.14.0 => 2.15.0
        com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.14.0 => 2.15.0
        com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.9.3
        com.github.curious-odd-man:rgxgen:1.4
        com.github.jknack:handlebars-jackson2:4.2.1
        com.github.jknack:handlebars:4.2.1
        com.github.joschi.jackson:jackson-datatype-threetenbp:2.12.5
        com.github.mifmif:generex:1.0.2
        com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre
        com.samskivert:jmustache:1.15
        commons-cli:commons-cli:1.5.0
        commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
        io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser:2.1.6
          commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
          io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser-v2-converter:2.1.6
          io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser-v3:2.1.6
          org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33 => 2.0  // <== HERE!!!
[...]
```

As far as I can see, there are two options here:

- Upgrading Gradle's OpenAPI plugin to make use of snakeyaml library version `2.0`;
- Forcing build process to make use of version `1.33` of this lib.

Tried some ways described in [Gradle's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html) to for instance force usage of a specific version of transient lib (here version `1.33` of snakeyaml lib), but without success.

Also slight "downgrades" of Micronaut's as well as OpenAPI Generator plugin's versions, but without success.

Any help, idea, hint very appreciated.

Thank you.

Regards

Christian

### Further investigation/information:

- Forcing usage of `snakeyaml:1.33` within `build.gradle` does **not** fix the problem:

  ```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33')
    }
  }

  [...]

  configurations {
    micronautBoms {
      resolutionStrategy.force 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33'
    }
  }

  [...]

  dependencies {
    [...]
    implementation('org.yaml:snakeyaml') {
      version {
        strictly '1.33'
      }
    }
    [...]
  }
  ```
- As evaluated above, OpenAPI Generator plugin makes use of `io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser:2.1.6` library, which itself declares to make use of `snakeyaml` library, but **without** specifying any version restrictions:

  ```
  $ curl --silent https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/parser/v3/swagger-parser-v3/2.1.14/swagger-parser-v3-2.1.14.pom | grep -A 1 -B 2 snakeyaml
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
           <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
       </dependency>
  ```

  Maybe **explicitly** declaring version restriction here (like `1.*` or `1.33`) would make Gradle recognize conflicting version requirements of this plugin and Micronaut (framework).

Comment: I think you have to bite the bullet and use :  id("org.openapi.generator") version "5.+"
This works for me

Comment: This probably comes from the never-ending dispute about the "bug" where yaml is being processed from untrusted sources. Snakeyaml author created a new version, which is probably not backward compatible. The same thing I have in quarkus now, no solution yet.

Comment: Related to [Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor: method <init>()V not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947862/getting-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-yaml-snakeyaml-constructor-safeconstruc)

Comment: "org.openapi.generator" version "6.6.0" threw the same snakeyml error for me. This happened on a Spring-Boot project. 

"7.0.0-beta" has been released on Jul 06, 2023. It resolved the issue. 

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin/7.0.0-beta